# How to redirect to another page and fire an event on that page

Tags: jquery, html

I created a button with id="work" when this button is clicked I am 
  trying to redirect to contact us page and the button with id="working- 
  us" is clicked in contact us page.

**jQuery**

```
$("#work").click(function() {
    window.location.replace("contactus.html");
    sessionStorage.setItem("workWithUS", "true");
    if (sessionStorage.workWithUs == "true") {
        $("#working-us").trigger(click);
        sessionStorage.removeItem("workWithUs");
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="work">Join our Team</a><button class="topic-btn d-flex" data-toggle="tab" href="#working-us" id="work2">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: I created a button with id="work" when this button is clicked I am trying to redirect to contact us page and the button with id="working- us" is clicked in contact us page.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML you are using, jQuery alone is not enough to go on.

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="work">Join our Team</a>
 <button class="topic-btn d-flex" data-toggle="tab" href="#working-us" id="work2">

Comment: it is redirecting to contact us page but not triggering the button how can I solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks OK but it is missing a closing bracket which will likely stop the if statement from triggering:

```
$("#work").click(function() {
  window.location.replace("contactus.html");
  sessionStorage.setItem("workWithUS", "true");
  if (sessionStorage.workWithUs == "true") {
    $("#working-us").trigger(click);
    sessionStorage.removeItem("workWithUs");
  }
});
```